# Represent infinity in the Num module

Tags: ocaml, infinity

In the [Num](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Num.html#TYPEnum) module, it is said :

> Numbers (type num) are arbitrary-precision rational numbers, plus the special elements 1/0 (infinity) and 0/0 (undefined).

I expected to find this `infinity` but can't find it. I guessed, then, that I could create it by hand :

```
let infinity = let one = Int 1 and zero = Int 0 in one // zero
```

But bum :

> Exception: Failure "create_ratio infinite or undefined rational number".

So, ok, there is this `val infinity : float` in Pervasives, let's find a `num_from_float`. Oh, there's no such function...

Well, does anyone know how to represent positive and negative infinity with Num ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, special numbers are disabled. This behavior can be controlled with the [Arith_status](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Arith_status.html) module. For example, to allow zero denominators, use the following:

```
Arith_status.set_error_when_null_denominator false
```

Once the flag is set, your infinity definition works fine:

```
let infinity = let one = Int 1 and zero = Int 0 in one // zero;;
val infinity : Num.num = <num 1/0>
float_of_num infinity;;
- : float = infinity
```

Comment: My problem is, then, why is it said that "inifinity" and "undefined" exist if they are not allowed by default ? Anyway, nice answer !

Comment: Maybe they should put in the documentation of Num that some behaviours are linked to the Arith_status module...

Comment: Yeah, a good question... I wish I have an answer, though. Probably, developers decided that special numbers cause more problems than solves. For example, when I was working with floats extensively, I used to open `Float.Safe` module that overrides all operations and fails, if any special number comes to play. It really helped me a lot in debugging. And yes, the documentation should be definitely updated, without lurking into the code, it is not easy to find out what is going wrong.